# How to get specific attribute from a JSON file in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, http-headers

By this code, I am getting header request in a string

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{

var userAgent = (JSON.stringify(req.headers)); 
console.log(userAgent);
```

On console, it is giving

```
{"accept":"text/plain","user-agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.26.5","postman-token":"73b
  6659a-4384-4ffa-81b3-154e9e41fc66","host":"localhost:3000","accept-encoding":"gz
  ip, deflate, br","connection":"keep-alive"}
```

Now I only want to get the "accept" key from the above JSON. How do I get this specific attribute?

Comment: Since `req.headers` is an [object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers) You can access the value using `console.log(req.headers.accept)` For a string you can use `console.log(JSON.parse(userAgent).accept)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple json object it can be used with sqare bracket or with dot operator.You can use

```
accept = userAgent["accept"]
console.log(accept)
```